# Why the command line does not respect the PATH order on OS X?

Tags: ssh, console

I added an ssh command inside `~/bin/ssh` and modified the `PATH` to include it, before other paths.

When I do run `which ssh` it will respond with `~/bin/ssh` but when I do run `ssh` it will just execute the `/usr/bin/ssh` instead.

I have no aliases for `ssh`.

What's the reason and how can I fix it?

Comment: I have the exact opposite behavior. `which tmux` shows the system-wide binary path, that has a missing shared library and can't start. For that reason, I've added a copy with fixed shared library reference to my home folder and added it to my path. `which` still references the system binary, `type` references the home binary, and just running runs the home binary as well. Strangely enough, `which -a tmux` shows the two binaries, but in reverse order in relation to my `$PATH`.

Answer (score 6):

Do not use `which`, use `type`. The `which` command in the default shell (bash) is an external utility which doesn't know about aliases and functions. On the other hand, `type` is an internal utility which will tell you whether its argument is an alias, a function, a built-in utility or an external command.

The `which` command is mentioned in tutorials and manuals only for historical reasons — 30 years ago the `type` command didn't exist everywhere, and some people have been slow to adapt.

For more details, including a discussion of historical and current shells, see [Why not use “which”? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then/85250#85250)

```
$ type cp
cp is aliased to `cp -i'
$ type mkcd
mkcd is a function
mkcd ()
{
…
}
$ type type
type is a shell builtin
$ type cat
cat is /bin/cat
```

In zsh, it's ok to use `which`: zsh has both `type` and `which` as built-in commands.

Also note that if you just installed or removed a program, the shell may have memorized its old location. For example, if you just installed your own version of a program in a directory that is ahead of the system directories in `$PATH`, the shell may keep invoking the program that came with the system. This is only an issue in shells that were already running at the time of the installation or removal. To refresh the shell's memory with current data, run the command `hash -r` or `hash COMMANDNAME`.

Answer (score 0):

Mistety solved, I had a function in bash_profile with this name...

Found it using: set |grep ssh

Comment: If you find that you want a function to wrap around `ssh`, you should probably use a [configuration file](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/ssh_config.5.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/5/ssh_config) instead. You can define shortcuts for host names, user names and other options in `~/.ssh/config`.